# abstract class annotation with overridable static attribute

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I've got abstract class:

```
import abc
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Abstract(abc.ABC):
    context_class: ClassVar[Type['BaseModel']]
    error: ClassVar[Type[Exception]]

    def __init__(self, data: Dict) -> None:
        self.context = self.context_class(**data)

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def process(self) -> None:
        pass
```

In it's inheritor I overridden attribute `context_class`:

```
class Context(BaseModel):
    email: str

class Concrete(Abstract):
    context_class = Context

    def process(self) -> None:
        print(self.context.email)
```

Mypy check fails with such error:

```
... error: "BaseModel" has no attribute "email"
```

Package versions:

- Python 3.8.2
- Mypy 0.770
- Pydantic 1.6.1

Answer (score 1):

Finally, answer is found. Generic types should be used:

```py
import abc
from typing import ClassVar, Type, Dict, Generic, TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel

T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseModel)


class Abstract(abc.ABC, Generic[T]):
    context_class: ClassVar[Type[T]]
    error: ClassVar[Type[Exception]]

    def __init__(self, data: Dict) -> None:
        self.context = self.context_class(**data)

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def process(self) -> None:
        pass


class Context(BaseModel):
    email: str


class Concrete(Abstract[Context]):
    context_class = Context

    def process(self) -> None:
        print(self.context.email)
```